# In Django, I have model in which based upon certain field , next field mapping of foreign-key has to be decided

Tags: django, django-models

models.py

```
class dummy(models.Model):
     GEOTYPE_CHOICES = (
(u'1', u'country'),
(u'2', u'state'),
(u'3', u'district'),
(u'4', u'pincode'))
geoType              =       models.CharField(max_length=9, choices=GEOTYPE_CHOICES)
if geoType==1:
    geoId            =       models.ForeignKey(CountryMaster,null=True,blank=True,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
elif geoType==2:
    geoId            =       models.ForeignKey(StateMaster,null=True,blank=True,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
elif geoType==3:
    geoId            =       models.ForeignKey(DistrictMaster,null=True,blank=True,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
else:
    geoId            =       models.ForeignKey(PincodeMaster,null=True,blank=True,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

if the user gives geotype as 2 then statemaster has be called in the geoId.like wise i need to do. But i am not able to register geoId in my database while migration.

any pointers on this will be a great help. thanks in advance.

Comment: That's not possible. You should use a `GenericForeignKey` for that. Here the `if` will only get evaluated when the *class* is constructed. So it would decide "at compile time" (well at the moment the server is *starting*).

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem hey any pointers on how to implement this use case using GenericForeignKey.

Comment: https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/10/13/how-to-use-generic-relations.html